# Jquery + Rails 3 + TokenInput Plugin + PrePopulate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, getjson, jquery-tokeninput

I am using tokeninput plugin (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html)  for multiple tags autocomplete and it is working just fine in `New` form.

Now I want to prePopulate the same in edit form; This is where I am having difficulty. I have created one file which return the values in json format (id and name). And if I copy those results from server log and put it in prePopulate option of tokeninput plugin it works just fine.

But when I do like this

```
prePopulate: k.getJSON("tag_list_pre")
```

where `tag_list_pre` is an action which returns the selected tags in json format.
If I alert the

```
alert(getJSON("tag_list_pre"));
```

it returns `[object Object]` and it doesn't pre populate anything.

I think the problem lies in some where when my file returns the json format data and on this side in the view it is not getting the desired results.

Similar Problem is asked in this question but yet not answered https://stackoverflow.com/q/5892326/489018

**UPDATE:**
I am now using the same method as in http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields?view=asciicast
I am using data-pre to and getting json format id and name string as required by token-input.

Sample output by that is

```
[{"id":"5","name":"payment-processing"},{"id":"8","name":"asd"},{"id":"15","name":"java"}]
```

Now my HTML text tag looks something like this.

```
<%= text_field_tag :project_tags, "data-pre" => @list1.to_json %>
```

where list1 is an array in id and name format sample output of @list1 looks like this.

```
[{:id=>"5", :name=>"payment-processing"}, {:id=>"8", :name=>"asd"}, {:id=>"15", :name=>"java"}]
```

and new tokenInput looks like this:

```
  k("#project_tags").tokenInput("tag_list", {
  prePopulate: k("#project_tags", k(this)).data("pre"),
  hintText: "Enter Tags for your Project",
  noResultsText: "No Such Tags",
  searchingText: "Looking for your Tags",
  preventDuplicates: true,
  theme: "facebook"
 });
```

**Now my problem is It is prepopulating nothing. Everything else works just fine.**

Thanks. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Have a look at my [answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656284/example-for-using-jquery-auto-complete-plugin-with-rails/8656721#8656721), especially the bottom with the recipe how to use token-inputs with JQuery in Rails3-

Comment: Hey @milebelt Thanks for your reply but I have tried that also and I couldn't figure out why that didn't work. So I have tried this option.
As this option does the same. Returns the JSON file. My Edit form is very complex it brings the data from 6-8 different models. Also I am not sure how to use .map(&:attributes).to_json. If you can provide more details about .map function that would be great.     Thanks.

Comment: @mliebelt I have added the code you mentioned in other question and I printed that below and I am getting following result.   
[{"created_at":"2011-12-28T12:26:30+05:30","id":10,"project_master_id":7,"tag_master_id":5,"updated_at":"2011-12-28T12:26:30+05:30"},{"created_at":"2011-12-28T12:26:30+05:30","id":11,"project_master_id":7,"tag_master_id":8,"updated_at":"2011-12-28T12:26:30+05:30"}]

While the desired json format is    
[{"id":"5","name":"payment-processing"},{"id":"8","name":"asd"}]

Comment: The part of the controller does the following thing: collect for each element of `@testers` its attributes as a map, returns the collection of all maps. You have to replace that by your specific code, especially where the `name` comes from. Something like: `@testers.map {|t| { m = Map.new; m[:id] => t.id; m[:name] => t.name; m }` where `name` is the method that returns the name of the  tester.

Comment: @mliebelt Hey I followed your instruction and change my text box to include data-pre
      <%= text_field_tag :project_tags, "data-pre" => list1.to_json %>
where list1 is an array containing id and name
But even after that nothing is prepopulated.
please guide me.

Comment: Have you added the necessary JavaScript code to your application, so that the pre-population can work? Have a look at the Railscasts again.

Comment: @mliebelt, kashyap - may I ask u to have a visit at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141176/facebook-style-jquery-tokeninput-script-retains-value-in-the-jquery-ui-modal-win? just  expecting   u to contribute there in a question about tokeninput. n i donno whether such a request is acceptable in SOF

Answer (score 0):

It's late, but I came across the exact problem. The error is in the call to [text_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag).

```
text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
```

As you can see, the second param is the value for the `text_field` and the third is the `options` param. You need to pass `nil` as `value` so that `data-pre` is passed as `option`.

```
<%= text_field_tag :project_tags, nil, "data-pre" => @list1.to_json %>
```

If you don't pass any `value`, it will take `data-pre` as the value for the `text_field`