# Dynamic javascript dropdown list with Rails and Ancestry

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I have created full categorization with Ancestry. The thing is,that I want to be able select from dropdown list.

When  I create new product on new action. I have fields for Product name, manufacturers and so on. And also added dropdown selection that shows all categories, I mean, root categories, subcategories and sub-subcategories. It looks very unclear so I want to implement something better using Javascript. So that, first off all I can select from root categories. When I do that, then shows up subcategories and so on. But without reloading page. How can I do that?

Example is here http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/dropdown-list-demo.php
I viewed similar questions abaut this kind of thing, but there never was included Javascript. HAML and so on.

But I am at learning process, so any advice would be great :)

Thanks!!

Comment: On that tutorial you've posted it tells you how to do it on the following page - http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/dropdown-code.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association

[example for using jquery auto complete plugin with rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656284/example-for-using-jquery-auto-complete-plugin-with-rails)